# MySQL How to get timedifference in unix timestamp

Tags: mysql

I have variable that holds value 1506947452 and need to extract minutes from that date with formula: started_data - now_date but started_date is in unix timestamp format 10-digit int number...that i received in ajax form and need to put in mysql query i try with this:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, 1506947452, UNIX_TIMESTAMP());
```

but i get this from terminal:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, '1506947452', UNIX_TIMESTAMP()) |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                  NULL |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

So how i can compare two dates in unix_timestamp format and get minutes?
I need to use unix_timestamp for start_date so others date format is not solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UNIX_TIMESTAMP is seconds seconds since '1970-01-01 00:00:00' in UTC. If you have a variable holding another UNIX_TIMESTAMP, you can get the difference and turn seconds to minutes (and round/truncate the result if needed):

```
 SELECT ROUND((UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-1506947452) / 60, 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

I fix it using:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, FROM_UNIXTIME('1506950440'), NOW());
```

the idea was to convert unixtime to normal date and then compare it with now() datetimestamp...so i get this:

```
mysql> SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, FROM_UNIXTIME('1506950440'), NOW());
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, FROM_UNIXTIME('1506950440'), NOW()) |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                         2 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```